# Infix to postfix conversion in C++

Tags: c++, performance, validation, math-expression-eval

Here is a program for conversion of an infix expression to a postfix expression using a stack. I would like to know how I could improve my checking for invalid input, make my code more expressive, and also improve the performance if possible.

I am using gcc 7.4.0. I can use C++17 if needed. This program compiles with C++11.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdexcept>

class digitException : public std::runtime_error
{
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

class unbalancedParentheses : public std::runtime_error
{
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

inline bool isOpeningParenthesis(char c) {return c == '(';}
inline bool isClosingParenthesis(char c) {return c == ')';}

inline bool isOperator(char c) 
{
    return 
        (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '^');
}

void checkValidInfix(const std::string& expr)
{
    std::stack<char> parentheses;
    for(auto curr : expr) {
        if(isdigit(curr))
            throw digitException {"Digits not supported."};

        if(isOpeningParenthesis(curr))
            parentheses.push(curr);

        else if(isClosingParenthesis(curr)) {
            if(parentheses.empty()) 
                throw unbalancedParentheses {"Parentheses unbalanced."};
            parentheses.pop();
        }
    }
    if(!parentheses.empty())
        throw unbalancedParentheses {"Parentheses unbalanced."};
}

void getInfixExpression(std::istream& is, std::string& expr) {
    is >> expr;
    checkValidInfix(expr);
}

bool isHigherPrecedenceThan(char currSymbol, char onStack)
//Returns true if precedence of current symbol is higher than 
//the symbol on stack.
//False otherwise. False if something other than an operand is given.
{
    if(!isOperator(currSymbol) || !isOperator(onStack))
        return false;

    if(currSymbol == '+' && onStack == '+') return false;
    if(currSymbol == '+' && onStack == '-') return false;
    if(currSymbol == '+' && onStack == '*') return false;
    if(currSymbol == '+' && onStack == '/') return false;
    if(currSymbol == '+' && onStack == '^') return false;

    if(currSymbol == '-' && onStack == '+') return false;
    if(currSymbol == '-' && onStack == '-') return false;
    if(currSymbol == '-' && onStack == '*') return false;
    if(currSymbol == '-' && onStack == '/') return false;
    if(currSymbol == '-' && onStack == '^') return false;

    if(currSymbol == '*' && onStack == '+') return true;
    if(currSymbol == '*' && onStack == '-') return true;
    if(currSymbol == '*' && onStack == '*') return false;
    if(currSymbol == '*' && onStack == '/') return false;
    if(currSymbol == '*' && onStack == '^') return false;

    if(currSymbol == '/' && onStack == '+') return true;
    if(currSymbol == '/' && onStack == '-') return true;
    if(currSymbol == '/' && onStack == '*') return false;
    if(currSymbol == '/' && onStack == '/') return false;
    if(currSymbol == '/' && onStack == '^') return false;

    if(currSymbol == '^' && onStack == '+') return true;
    if(currSymbol == '^' && onStack == '-') return true;
    if(currSymbol == '^' && onStack == '*') return true;
    if(currSymbol == '^' && onStack == '/') return true;
    if(currSymbol == '^' && onStack == '^') return true;
}

std::string convertToPostfix(const std::string& infix)
{
    std::stack<char> operatorStack;
    std::string result;
    auto inputSymbol = infix.begin();

    while(inputSymbol != infix.end()) {
        char currSymbol = *inputSymbol;

        if(std::isalpha(currSymbol))
            result.push_back(currSymbol);

        else if(isOperator(currSymbol)) {
            if(operatorStack.empty() ||
                     isOpeningParenthesis(operatorStack.top()))
                operatorStack.push(currSymbol);

            else 
                if(isHigherPrecedenceThan(currSymbol, operatorStack.top()))
                    operatorStack.push(currSymbol);

                else {
                    while(!operatorStack.empty() && 
                    !isOpeningParenthesis(operatorStack.top()) &&
                    !isHigherPrecedenceThan(currSymbol, operatorStack.top())) {
                        result.push_back(operatorStack.top());
                        operatorStack.pop();
                    }
                    operatorStack.push(currSymbol);
                }
        }

        else if(isOpeningParenthesis(currSymbol))
            operatorStack.push(currSymbol);

        else if(isClosingParenthesis(currSymbol)) {
            while(!isOpeningParenthesis(operatorStack.top())) {
                result.push_back(operatorStack.top());
                operatorStack.pop();
            }
            operatorStack.pop();
        }

        ++inputSymbol;
    }
    while(!operatorStack.empty()) {
        result.push_back(operatorStack.top());
        operatorStack.pop();
    }

    return result;
}


int main()
{
    try {
        std::string infixExpr;
        std::cout << "Enter Infix Expression: ";
        getInfixExpression(std::cin, infixExpr);
        std::cout << "Postfix Expression: " << convertToPostfix(infixExpr) 
            << "\n";
    }
    catch(const unbalancedParentheses& up) {
        std::cerr << up.what() << "\n";
    }
    catch(const digitException& de) {
        std::cerr << de.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Here are some examples :

```
Enter Infix Expression: a-b-c
Postfix Expression: ab-c-
```

```
Enter Infix Expression: a*b+c/g-h^j
Postfix Expression: ab*cg/+hj^-
```

```
Enter Infix Expression: a+b*c+(d*e+f)*g
Postfix Expression: abc*+de*f+g*+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Make sure all paths return a value

The `isHigherPrecedenceThan` routine returns an explicit value for many different combinations of characters, but if none of those conditions match, the routine falls through and does not return a value.  It would better to make sure that a value is always returned, as in the following suggestion.

### Simplify your code

In the `isHigherPrecedenceThan` routine, the code only returns `true` in nine specific cases and false in all other cases.  For this reason, we can greatly simplify the code:

```
bool isHigherPrecedenceThan(char currSymbol, char onStack) {
    return  ((currSymbol == '*' || currSymbol == '/' || currSymbol == '^') 
                && (onStack == '+' || onStack == '-')) 
            || (currSymbol == '^' 
                && (onStack == '*' || onStack == '/' || onStack == '^'));
}
```

### Consider the use of objects

If you had an `Operator` class, a number of things would be simplified.  For example, instead of having the code above as a standalone function, one could implement it as `operator>` and keep all of operator-specific parts in once place.

### Use return values

The `main` routine defines an empty string and the passes it to the `convertToPostfix` routine to fill in.  I'd expect instead that `convertToPostfix` would return the string.  Also, if you have the C++17 `std::optional` available, I think I'd prefer that to using exceptions.

### Consider better error checking

The current code accepts `;;';'[]^_=!@#$%` as a valid infix string.  That doesn't seem correct.  It may be better to check for only valid characters.

### Consider unary vs. binary functions

If we write "-8" it's clear that "-" is being used as a unary function with a single argument "8".  If we write "9-8" the "-" is a binary function that has a somewhat different purpose.  The current code makes no such distinction and accepts "-a" and renders "a-" which may be acceptable, but it's unlikely that "a^" is currectly translated as "a^".